# Reload Collection View in a Collection View Cell through delegation

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a controller (A) with a Collection View that features 2 cell classes. One of them (B) contains another Collection View. After doing some research, I still cannot figure out how to update the cells in (B) from (A) or elsewhere to get what I want.

**Issues**

(B) does not reload properly when its button is pressed: the cell with whom the button was tied is still visible even though it is deleted from the `userFriendRequests` array in (A) in its delegate method. As a bonus I get a crash when I scroll to a new cell in (B) stating that "index is out of range" on the line `cell.user = userFriendRequests[indexPath.row]`.

**What I Have**

Controller (A)

```
protocol UserFriendRequestsDelegate: class {

func didPressConfirmFriendButton(_ friendId: String?)
}

/...

fileprivate var userFriendRequests = [User]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if userFriendRequests.isEmpty == false {

        switch indexPath.section {

        case 0:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: friendRequestCellId, for: indexPath) as! UserFriendRequests
            cell.userFriendRequests = userFriendRequests
            cell.delegate = self
            return cell
        case 1:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserFriendCell
            let user = users[indexPath.row]
            cell.user = user
            return cell
        default:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserFriendCell
            return cell
        }
    }

/...

extension AddFriendsController: UserFriendRequestsDelegate {

internal func didPressConfirmFriendButton(_ friendId: String?) {

    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid, let friendId = friendId else {
        return
    }

    let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users_friends").child(uid).child(friendId)
    let friendRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users_friends").child(friendId).child(uid)
    let value = ["status": "friend"]

    userRef.updateChildValues(value) { (error, ref) in

        if error != nil {
            return
        }

        friendRef.updateChildValues(value, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

            if error != nil {
                return
            }

            self.setUpRequestsStatusesToConfirmed(uid, friendId: friendId)

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                let index = self.currentUserFriendRequests.index(of: friendId)

                self.currentUserFriendRequests.remove(at: index!)

                for user in self.userFriendRequests {

                    if user.id == friendId {

                        self.userFriendRequests.remove(at: self.userFriendRequests.index(of: user)!)
                    }
                }
                self.attemptReloadOfCollectionView()
            })
        })
    }
}
```

PS: `self.attemptReloadOfCollectionView()` is a func that simply invalidates a timer, sets it to 0.1 sec and then calls `reloadData()` on (A)'s Collection View.

CollectionViewCell (B)

```
weak var delegate: UserFriendRequestsDelegate?
var userFriendRequests = [User]()

/...


@objc fileprivate func confirmFriendButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    delegate?.didPressConfirmFriendButton(friendId)
}

/...

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return userFriendRequests.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: friendRequestCellId, for: indexPath) as! FriendRequestCell

    cell.user = userFriendRequests[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

/...

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let firstName = userFriendRequests[indexPath.row].first_name, let lastName = userFriendRequests[indexPath.row].last_name, let id = userFriendRequests[indexPath.row].id else {
        return
    }

    nameLabel.text = firstName + " " + lastName
    friendId = id
    confirmButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(confirmFriendButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

**What I want to achieve**

Update (B) when a `User` is removed from the `userFriendRequests` array in (A), this `User` being identified by his `id` passed by (B) through delegation.

Any good soul that might have an idea on how to tackle this issue ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Just to clarify, you have 1 viewController and 2 collectionViews?

Comment: Indeed @JoséNeto. Controller (A) implements a collection view: if `userFriendRequests` contains elements, then the first section of this collection view will register/dequeue cells defined in class (B). These class (B) cells also implement a collection view from the `userFriendRequests` data source passed from (A). My problem is that the collection view in (B) does not reload when I update `userFriendRequests` in (A) and reload (A)'s collection view. This triggers the issues I described above in the question.

Comment: Just for testing, did you try to use notification? when you do something in controller A you use notification to notify B so he can reload the content of collection view?